# installed windows phone sdk 8.0 on 32 bit oerating system but not works?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have installed Windows Phone sdk 8.0 on 32 bit operating system with already installed visual studio 2012 ultimate sdk successfully installed from command prompt c://wpexpress_2full.exe/layout

now I have tried running from visual studio but I found no option to select win phone project option I used this link to install sdk

```
 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471
```

Comment: [Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471): *"System Requirements: Operating system type: Windows 8 **64-bit** (x64) client versions"*

Comment: any windows phone sdk that works on visual studio 2012 ultimate 32 bit os any SDK may be 7 or etc

Comment: only give me the link of visual studio express 2012 for windows phone a direct download link

Answer (score 0):

They make clear on [downloadpage](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) about the installation requirement.
Windows Phone emulator uses Hyper-V, which also requires Hyper-V requires a 64-bit system that has Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).